# Does a BJT Class A Amplifier act in Reverse Mode?

Tags: amplifier

[image]

The signal above has negative voltage, so should I take it that it is positively clamped or biased? Or, does the NPN go in Reverse Mode, which I don't think it does (as Reverse Mode only explains the later half of the sine wave, not the negative OUT of the first half).

Comment: Question doesn't make sense.

Comment: The input signal does NOT go negative, it has small variations around a chosen operating point. Compared to this operating point (for example 0.7 V) it goes down to 0.65 V, compared to 0.7 V that is -50 mV. Which is negative, but only compared to the 0.7 V !

Answer (score 5):

The diagram you show is a gross simplification.  In particular, it doesn't show how the transistor is kept biased so that the DC output is near the middle of its range.

The basic circuit won't work with negative inputs.  In a real circuit, the biasing provides a base level that the input both adds to and subtracts from, without the result going negative for the intended volume range.

Comment: The circuit seems like a *really* gross simplification; the plots might have been accurate if the left plot were *current* and the right were *voltage*, and both showed signals that stayed above zero, but if the input plot shows voltage I would think the output plot should ride the supply voltage until the input gets very close to 0.7, then quickly drop to 0, and then start smoking as base-emitter current increases exponentially with voltage.